# Issue with CreateRemoteThread causing target process crash

Tags: c++, multithreading, debugging, winapi, code-injection

I am encountering a problem when using CreateRemoteThread to inject a thread into a target process. The target process crashes without clear error messages, and I'm having trouble identifying the root cause. I've thoroughly reviewed my code and incorporated debugging statements, but I'm still stuck.

**Code Overview:**

game.cpp

```
int player = 10;

int main()
{
  while (1)
  {
    std::cout << "Number of player = "
              << player
              << " | address of "
              << &player << std::endl;
    Sleep(3000);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

injector.cpp

```
const WCHAR* TARGET_PROCESS_NAME = L"game.exe";
const DWORD MEMORY_ALLOCATION_SIZE = 1 << 12;

DWORD WINAPI HackThread(int * lpParameter)
{
  int *player = lpParameter;
  *player = 100;
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  auto pid = getProcessId(TARGET_PROCESS_NAME);
  if (pid == 0)
  {
    std::cerr << "Error: Unable to find process " << TARGET_PROCESS_NAME << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);
  if (hProcess == NULL)
  {
    std::cerr << "Error: Unable to open process. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }


  LPVOID lpBaseAddress = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, nullptr, MEMORY_ALLOCATION_SIZE, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
  if (lpBaseAddress == nullptr)
  {
    std::cerr << "Error: Unable to allocate memory in the remote process. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    return 1;
  }

  DWORD oldProtect;
  if (!VirtualProtectEx(hProcess, lpBaseAddress, MEMORY_ALLOCATION_SIZE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READ, &oldProtect))
  {
    std::cerr << "Error: Unable to modify memory protection. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, lpBaseAddress, MEMORY_ALLOCATION_SIZE, MEM_RELEASE);
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    return 1;
  }

  int valueToSend = 0x00791000;
  if (!WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, lpBaseAddress, &valueToSend, sizeof(int), NULL))
  {
    std::cerr << "Error: Unable to write to remote process memory. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, lpBaseAddress, MEMORY_ALLOCATION_SIZE, MEM_RELEASE);
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    return 1;
  }

  HANDLE hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, nullptr, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)HackThread, lpBaseAddress, NULL, nullptr);
  if (hThread == NULL)
  {
    std::cerr << "Error: Unable to create remote thread. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, lpBaseAddress, MEMORY_ALLOCATION_SIZE, MEM_RELEASE);
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    return 1;
  }

  WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);

  // Clean up resources
  VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, lpBaseAddress, MEMORY_ALLOCATION_SIZE, MEM_RELEASE);
  return 0;
}
```

**Problem Description:**

I'm attempting to inject a thread into a target process using CreateRemoteThread. It like DLL injection but instead of DLL I only want to run a HackThread. However, the target process crashes without providing specific error details. I've ensured proper memory allocation, protection modification, and data writing. Additionally, I've added debugging statements, but I can't pinpoint the issue.

**Specific Questions:**

- Can I use "DLL injection without DLL"?
- What is the root of this cause?

**Additional Context:**

- hThread != 0
- lpBaseAddress != 0
- Compiled in x86 debug mode

I appreciate any guidance or insights into resolving this issue. Thank you!

Comment: (1) _"...Can I use "DLL injection without DLL"?..."_ No. (2) The address you pass for `HackThread` (to `CreateRemoteThread`) only exists (is valid) in your process; so the remote thread tries to start at an invalid address.

Comment: The (1) maybe true, but (2) is seem not correct. I have RE game.exe and run game.exe, &player is the same

Comment: You said we can't create independent remote thread to target process. It must follow some theory, isn't it?

Comment: [`CreateRemoteThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createremotethread) `lpStartAddress` - _"...The function must exist in the __remote__ process. ..."_ So the address you pass here must be a valid virtual address in the remote processes address space and obviously be a thread function.

Comment: Also if this cast is required to get the program to compile:  `(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)HackThread,` then the definition of `HackThread` is incorrect.

Comment: Ah, that right!

Comment: @TuLeAnh You *should* put the code for `HackThread` into a DLL, inject the DLL into the target process, and then signal the DLL to call `HackThread` inside the remote process. But you are not doing that. The only way to make this code work is to allocate a block of executable memory in the target process, copy all of the machine code from `HackThread` into that memory, and then have the remote thread execute that memory as a function. You can't call a function across process boundaries, like you are attempting to do